# Waiting for the result of a function called from somewhere else

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, async-await, promise

I have a Node server where I want to integrate Paypal. I have one module that is supposed to return the access token from paypal. This module has one async function and looks something like this:

```
let token: string | null = null;

export async function getToken() {
    if (token === null) {
        token = await requestTokenFromPaypal()
    }

    return token;
}

export function resetToken() { token = null }
```

```
main:
getToken()
getToken()
getToken()
// -> I want all calls to wait until the first request for the token is finished and then resolve to the token
// -> Currently the token will be requested three times
```

The resetToken function is called if the other requests yield 401 and the token is invalid. So a new token is needed. But now every call to the getToken will result in a token request until the first request is finished and saved to token.

So how can I wait for the result from another function that was called from a different piece of code? I have already thought about saving the promise or something like that but I cant wrap my head around it.

I also tried to google it but only get the standart async code questions. Please refer me if you find other similar questions.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do in code. For example, how do you call your functions? Don't forget to assign `token` to the  result of `await requestTokenFromPaypal()` in your `getToken` function. And you don't need to return a resolved promise. The async function already returns a promise, returning from that function will be the same as doing `return token`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking whether the token is available, you could check whether the request for the token has already been started.

You can do this by checking on the tokenPromise that is basically just a wrapper around the token.

```
let tokenPromise = null

export async function getToken() {
    if (!tokenPromise) {
        tokenPromise = requestTokenFromPaypal()
    }

    return tokenPromise
}

export function resetToken() { tokenPromise = null }
```

In case you wonder, directly returning the tokenPromise without awaiting for it will actually have the same effect as awaiting for it and then returning the token.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a promise, and `.then` it.

```
let token: string | null = null;

export async function getToken() {
    if (token === null) {
        return requestTokenFromPaypal() // this function should return a promise
        /* (node-fetch would be the easiest way to do that, but whatever works) */
    }

    return Promise.resolve(token);
}

export function resetToken() { token = null }


//later, somewhere else in your code
getToken().then(function(token) {
  //do something with 'token'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I want to avoid calling the requestTokenFromPaypal multiple times. But if I now call the getToken multiple times before the token is set the function gets called multiple times

Comment: Not a concern if you follow what I explained above

Comment: You never store anything other than `null` in `token`?

Comment: It's global so I assumed it was being set from `requestTokenFromPaypal`, but it could be done from this getToken instead. Either way works.

Comment: I do not have control over when the getToken is called. So if two people access a certain link in the same moment the getToken() is called at the same time and thus they would both run the requestTokenFromPaypal and not wait both for one execution of the function. I think the storing of a token as suggested by IAmDranged is the better solution